# How does Swift's for-in loop work?

Tags: swift

With Java's Stream API it is possible to use ***functional* [internal iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) over collections**, just like

```
collection.forEach(out::println)
```

Is Swift's following for-each loop construct...

```
for i in names {
    println(i)
}
```

...merely syntactic sugar for an internal (functional) iteration that could also be paraphrased as the following imperative for loop?

```
for var i = 0; i < names.count; i++ {
    println(names[i])
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID431) states that for a `for`-`in` loop,

> The `generate()` method is called on the collection expression to obtain a value of a generator type—that is, a type that conforms to the `Generator` protocol. The program begins executing a loop by calling the `next()` method on the stream. If the value returned is not `None`, it is assigned to the *item* pattern, the program executes the statements, and then continues execution at the beginning of the loop. Otherwise, the program does not perform assignment or execute the statements, and it is finished executing the `for`-`in` statement.

So, we can say that

```
for i in names {
    println(i)
}
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
var g = names.generate()  // "var" because next() is a mutating function
while let i = g.next() {  // "let" pattern because next() returns an optional
    println(i)
}
```

As for functional iteration, well, we have SequenceType's [`func map<T>(_ transform: (Element) -> T) -> [T]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FPSs12SequenceType3mapu__Rq_S__Fq_FzFzqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Elementqd__GSaqd___).